# Error in "main" thread, NoClassDefFound : Classname in Java servlet ..How to run the class file?

Tags: java, servlets, classpath

I have a project where I am using a start.HTML page to invoke javascript call which inturn calls a java servlet Enquiry.java and this calls a php file myPhp.php. This php file scrapes data from a famous music site and sends data back to Enquiry.java as an XML(file or string, my choice).
So, I have to have this xml data on php page making myPhp.php act like a xml file, which my servlet uses to extract data from.

Now, I have to compile and run my java servlet on putty and run html on browser and do the rest.
I am able to compile my file perfectly.
I have set CLASSPATH to ~/tomcat/jakarta/common/lib where all jars are placed.
I do `>javac -classpath $CLASSPATH/servlet.jar:$CLASSPATH/json-rpc-1.0.jar Enquiry.java`
Compiled fine.

Now, I must be having a Enquiry.class somewhere (I think in my classpath)
I stop tomcat. Transfer this class file to where my .java file is. Start tomcat.
Now, I need to run it.

I do `java -classpath $CLASSPATH/servlet.jar:$CLASSPATH/json-rpc-1.0.jar Enquiry`
I get: `Error in "main" thread, NoClassDefFound : Enquiry`
I have both in current folder only. I still get a exception
I want to know what is wrong?

If I add a . before Enquiry, I get: `Error in "main" thread, NoClassDefFound : javax.servlet.http.httpresponse exception`
If I add a `java -cp .:$CLASSPATH...` then i get: `Error in "main" thread, NoClassDefFound : Main exception`

Please help me to resolve my classpath and run my java servlet cleanly.

Comment: There should be no need to mess with Java classpath settings when running a servlet in a web-application. Just build it as a WAR file and put it in the webapps folder of your servlet container. Dependant jar files should go in WEB-INF/lib inside the WAR.

Comment: Why don't you pack your class file together with json-rpc-1.0.jar in a WAR file and deploy that to Tomcats webapp directory?

Answer (score 0):

When creating a servlet, you usually (if not always) create it as a part of a web application packaged as a `WAR` file. To run your servlet, you take the packaged WAR file and put it in the deployment folder of the servlet container you're using. Since you aparently are using Tomcat, this would probably be in the `tomcat/webapps` folder. [This tutorial](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/appdev/index.html) is a good place to start to learn about developing and deploying web applications. The only Java process you should have to start is your servlet container.

Comment: I haven't used an WAR files. I just want to compile and run servlet on putty and open my html in browser, add data to form, send it to servlet, servlet calls php, php extracts data from say imdb.com, puts it in xml form, servlet then extracts xml data from php, makes it into a JSON object and sends back to xmlhttp object in html file and display it in a tabular form.

Comment: You mean putty, as in the ssh client for Windows? Or do you mean jetty, as in the servlet container? I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but a servlet container is a lot more than just classpath. It's also request and response handling, so trying to run it standalone outside a servlet container is not something I would recommend, if at all possible.

Comment: Yes, ssh client. Before i run my html on browser to fill the form, i must compile and run my servlet at the backend so that my html can make a call to it. I m able to compile the java file. But, it just doesn't recognise my .class file at runtime. Throws a NoClassDefinition found. This must mean that i am not handlng my classpath while running, right?

Comment: Your servlet needs to run in a servlet container. You can't just run it from the command line. Take a look at the tutorial I linked to.